# Angular 2 Rounding numbers - percentage

Tags: angularjs

How can i generate this percentage: number * 100 ( ex. 0.050 * 100 = 5.5 )
  i get the number from db like 0.050 but need to be showed as 5.5

actual code

```
  <strong>{{d.AllowancePercentage}} %</strong>
```

Comment: There seem to be a [percent pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/PercentPipe-pipe.html), take a look at the docs

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I found is this:

```
{{ (d.AllowancePercentage * 100) | number:'1.1-2' }}
```

Here's the official documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/PercentPipe